# Disable Windows 10 Settings Header

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently upgraded my **Windows 10** and now the **Settings** window shows this header with things like Microsoft account / OneDrive / your phone / update / rewards etc.

**How to disable this annoying header?** There is no dismiss button...

[image: Windows 10 Settings Header]

Note: it doesn't seem to appear for everyone, on another (identical Windows 10 installation) it did not appear. So seems to be some kind of A/B test thing (?).

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution [here](https://geekermag.com/how-to-enable-header-in-windows-10-settings-app/). For now this seems to work (tested in Windows 20H2 and 21H1):

1. Download **ViveTool** from [**GitHub**](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe/releases).
2. **Unblock** the .zip (right-click, Properties, "Unblock"), **unpack** it.
3. Open **Administrator PowerShell** (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>)
4. Navigate to the ViveTool folder and **run** it like this:

   ```
   .\vivetool.exe addconfig 18299130 1
   .\vivetool.exe addconfig 31950543 1
   ```
5. **Reboot**

Comment: The new ViveTool v0.3.1 uses a different syntax: `vivetool /disable /id:<featureid>`.
Anyhow, tried this version and an older one, didn't work. I did manage to get rid of the one item about the default browser while testing different IDs from Vive's included feature dictionary, so it may just be a matter of finding the right ID for your build.
Not sure how long this modification lasts, though…

Answer (score 0):

At this point this header is not removable.

Also, I see this on Windows Insider here, but not yet on Windows 10 21H1 production. This may differ by installation.

I do not usually work in Settings, so I just ignore it.

[Remove Setup Header](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/remove-disable-hide-windows-10-settings-header/29afe867-0a9b-4ffd-b51c-8435a5b41045?auth=1)

> That new 'Feature' is certainly dividing people, most are not
> impressed with that, unfortunately there is no way to disable that,
> not even a registry hack as of yet. Hopefully Microsoft will give us a
> way to disable that in a future update, but for now, there is not way